# UIStepper in hidden view interferes with UIButton in another UIView?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uibutton, uistepper

I'm having a problem with a UIButton in a UIView: part of the button does not respond to touches. The cause is a UIStepper in another UIView. But, that view is hidden!

Why does the system think a UIStepper in another, hidden, view is still somehow there?
(The UIStepper does not receive actual events.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem by really removing the view with the stepper from the views hierarchy instead of just hiding it.